# Testing SMTP errors in my Java app

Tags: java, testing, smtp

My Java application encountered an issue in production where the SMTP server is rejecting mails sent to more than x destinations at once. I would like to test the behavior of the application in that situation.

I found [Dumbster Fake SMTP Server](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/) that is very nice but does not seem to offer a way to reject messages in some tests.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could test this specific scenario ?

Comment: The only suggestion I have is that Dubmster is open source project so you can take a look at extending that. Besides source code seems to be rather small.

Comment: It's a quite old question but I wanted to provide an update.I have created a JUnit extension to write integration tests with a SMTP server emulation. It's based on SubEthaSMTP and the related software FakeStmp. It's quite easy to use. Please have a look to github.com/sleroy/fakesmtp-junit-runner/. If you want some more alternatives you can try mailtrap.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know Dumbster, but SubEthaSMTP does have this capability. Maybe the simplest solution is to extend the Wiser class (which implements a simple SMTP server specifically for testing) by overriding its accept method, returning false after the x. recipient.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative I can suggest is through writing a Junit test with EasyMock/ Mockito and simulating the exception that you see on production. You can focus on the part of code that you suspect and issue with and drill down on and fix the root cause. Obviously, if the above suggested SMTP services give you the capability to simulate the error, they may give you  better confidence.